# assigning int to Pk[Long]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I am a newbie with scala, play and anorm. Trying to figure out.

Right now I created a case class like ;

```
case class Company(
             var id: Pk[Long] ,
             var name: String,
             var appid: String,
             var appSecret: String,
             var iban: String)
```

I can create dummy object to insert like this;

```
var c: Company  = Company(anorm.NotAssigned,"Test Inc","test123456","4506xk23iosc44545","TR324349999000342")
```

But I can't populate a dummy object with id field (later i'll use it to update model)

When I type

```
var c: Company  = Company(7,"Test Inc","test123456","4506xk23iosc44545","TR324349999000342")
```

I got error that saying `type mismatch; found : Int(7) required: anorm.Pk[Long]`

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pk has two subclasses NotAssigned and Id which is when it has got a value, so Id(7)